# Long standing Google Earth path puzzle

Tags: google-earth, kml

I've searched for a solution to this mystery for years. It's perhaps best described with an illustration

[image]

In that example I want a solid line to trace the path, on an otherwise clear map window. The residue prevents that.

Comment: Is this a problem with the Google Earth PC application or the webapp?

Comment: Google Earth desktop PC application.